# Esperar a que un elemento se cargue en selenium antes de acceder a el

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Estoy usando selenium 4 y necesito acceder a varios elementos, entre los cuales se encuentran unicamente botones y labels, no quiero utilizar temporizadores ya que voy a ejecutar el codigo en situaciones muy abstractas, investigando he visto que puedo esperar a que un elemento se cargue antes de usarlo para evitarse usar temporizadores.
Este es el codigo que he implementado:

```
def write_on_element(element_id, text, delay):
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30, poll_frequency=10)
    try:
        element = wait.until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, element_id)))
    except TimeoutException:
        time.sleep(delay)
        try:
            element = driver.find_element(By.ID, element_id)
        except NoSuchElementException:
            raise Exception(
                f"Elemento con id '{element_id}' no encontrado después de esperar {delay} segundos")
    element.send_keys(text)


chrome_options = ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")

service = Service(chromedriver_path)
driver = Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)

driver.get(url)

write_on_element("i0116", "Texto de prueba", 5)

driver.quit()
```

El problema que estoy teniendo es que no me escribe nada y al cabo de un tiempo se cierra solo. Existe alguna forma de hacerlo?, O algún cambio en mi código para que funcione correctamente?

Gracias de antemano

**CORRECCIÓN**
Se cierra porque se la excepcion `NoSuchElementException` cierra la pagina cuando no encuentra el elemento que estoy buscando, pero no estoy consiguiendo controlar la excepcion correctamente

Comment: Hola marcos, puedes intentar esperar a que sea clickable despues de esperar que sea localizado? wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable)

Comment: Con eso si funciona gracias